# Discutírtelo x discutirlo contigo

Tags: expresiones, pronombres, preposiciones

En la canción "Mi historia entre tus dedos" el cantante dice:

> te marchas ¿y qué?
>
> yo no intento discutírtelo
>
> lo sabes y lo sé

Investigué esta expresión **discutírtelo** y la gran mayoría de los resultados se limitan a esta canción.

¿Es común usar este tipo de conjugación en conversaciones cotidianas? Lo más común (o correcto) no sería decir algo como "No intento **discutirlo contigo**". o "No intento **discutirlo con usted**" en lugar de "no intento **discutírtelo**".

De la misma forma en la canción "El sol no regresa" dice la cantante:

> Hoy te intento contar
>
> que todo va bien
>
> aunque no te lo creas

¿Por qué el uso de este "aunque **no te lo creas**"?

¿No sería correcto decir simplemente "aunque **no lo creas**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Discutir](https://dle.rae.es/discutir) es un verbo transitivo, donde el complemento directo es el tema que se discute. Como se ve en el ejemplo del DLE, la persona con la que se discute suele venir introducida por la preposición *con*:

> Discutieron con el contratista sobre el precio de la obra

Por tanto, la expresión más común y natural es, como bien dices, "no lo discuto contigo" o "no intento discutirlo contigo". Sin embargo, la expresión

- [No te lo discuto](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no%20te%20lo%20discuto%22)

está relativamente extendida con el significado "estoy de acuerdo con lo que acabas de decir, no tengo nada que decir en contra". En esta expresión, la persona con la que se discute es el complemento indirecto. No conozco otras expresiones que usen el verbo *discutir* de esta manera (en España), aunque parece que este uso está más extendido en otras regiones. La frase de la canción

- No intento discutírtelo

es simplemente "no te lo intento discutir".

En cuanto a "aunque no te lo creas", el DLE indica en qué caso se puede usar *[creer](https://dle.rae.es/creer)* como pronominal ("creerse algo"):

> 1. tr. Tener algo por cierto sin conocerlo de manera directa o sin que esté comprobado o demostrado. *El catecismo enseña lo que hay que creer*. U. t. c. prnl. *Se lo cree todo*.

Los demás significados de *creer* usan la forma no pronominal. Por ejemplo, en el sentido de "opinar" o "pensar":

- Creo que no tenemos arroz

no se puede usar "me".

Comment: Muy detallada respuesta, a la que sólo quiero agregar que “discutirle algo al alguien” es la forma más común en mi dialecto cuando la idea es que el sujeto, unilateralmente, se enfrenta con palabras con su interlocutor para rebatir o poner en entredicho algo. “Discutir algo con alguien” sugiere más bien una conversación, que puede ser acalorada o no. Si me ofrecés algo y yo **discuto el precio con vos**, es una negociación; si yo **te discuto el precio**, es que directamente te planteo (con algún argumento) que me niego a pagarlo.